# Clean install Linux on spare drive of Mac Pro 5.1 Mojave workstation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, drivers, graphics-card

My Mac Pro has been upgraded to Mojave using a Nvidia (MSI) Geforce GTX 680 card (it is metal compatible and I can see the boot screen to change which drive I boot on using options key).

I want to install a single boot Ubuntu Desktop with the Geforce GTX 680 drivers on a spare SSD.  I want to be able to run MaaS (Metal as a Service), JuJu, Kubernetes etc on native Ubuntu so please don't offer a virtualization suggestion.

I flashed Ubuntu 19.04 onto a USB stick and it seems to boot but of course it doesn't have the Mac specific driver support for the GTX GPU.  I get a completely blank screen, so cannot load any driver or set up ssh to the Mac Pro and add the drivers using terminal etc.

------------update-----------------
I formatted the USB using the Mac drive utility, and then burned the image using balenaEtcher, and it boots fine on a normal Ubuntu workstation (HP).

The Mac Pro can read enough of the image to pull up grub, but the screen goes blank. I am assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that if the boot failed it would leave an error message and the fact that the screen is blank is a sign that the screen drivers themselves are up the duff.

Is it possible to format a bootable SSD on an Ubuntu workstation, add the nVidia drivers, and get the Mac to boot from the drive if I format the SSD to Mac before install Ubuntu?

Comment: You need to run the live session with an additional boot parameter, `nomodeset`, and also add it when booting for the first time until you install the proper Nvidia drivers.

Comment: I get the grub menu, but nomodeset doesn't make any difference. Probably something to do with the Mac specific drivers on the GTX 680.